# Customer Account Registration Form Customer Group Assign in Frontend Magento2

Tags: customer, customer-account, customer-group, customer-registration, create-account

Magento2 module Require Where I will be able to assign customer group from frontend when Customer will Create Magento 2 customer account?

Answer (score 1):

Here I Developed a module and you can get the total solution from here 
https://github.com/MageRakesh/Customer/tree/master/MageRakesh/Customer